# How Do I Create Bootstrap Modal Popup?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I Want to create pop up.I am working on house of blouse website. in that when i click country name text popup is showing.
please check
http://www.houseofblouse.com/index

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: please check http://www.houseofblouse.com/index page ,on that  page click country name which is at top of page.that is wanted.please give any example like that

Comment: You need to add more and complete details so it will be easy to understand what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap, and as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp):

First create a button that triggers the modal

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Then create the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for a sample. source(http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In that website popup there two  buttons in popup.one is agree another is cancel.if we click agree another pop up is displayed which consists country names,if any country name is selected pop up is closed.if we clicked cancel button on first pop up then pop up is closed

Comment: @shaik.jameer we are not here to make your requirements successful. We are here to help each other. If you want each and every thing similar please hire some freelancer, or post different question for different problems.

Answer (score 0):

your code -->[This is what you are looking for your website..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpTxd.png)

first popup will display to user and on click on Agree button second popup will be display.

Comment: please check "houseofblouse.com/index page" ,on that page click country name which is at top of page.that is wanted.please give any example like that.I want same pop up like that.

Comment: I need to attach any css and jquery for it

Comment: i have given sample code as per your requirement just add your logic to display country names in Model body section.. when user select country name then just close popup.Use this line to hide popup-->   eg. $("#contryName).click(function(){   ("#FirstModelName").hide('model');   });